# Find numbers with repeated digits

Tags: excel-formula

I have numbers in column A with 2 repeated digits, i need to find all numbers in column H that match the same repeated digits at the same position and show theme on column B separated by commas. This must be done for each number in column A
Example; if number in column A is 022, it should retrieve 022, 122, 222,322.... from column H and put it in column B as follows: 022,122, 222, 322, 422........ If number in column A is 313, it should retrieve 313, 323, 333, 343....... If number in column A is 2722, it should retrieve numbers 2122, 2222, 2322..... 2722, 2822.....

=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;IF((MID(A13;1;2)=MID(H:H;1;2))+(MID(A13;2;2)=MID(H:H;2;2))>0;H:H;""))
i try to use this formula but it doesnt't retrive only the numbers with repeated digits at the same position

Comment: I believe you'll also need to check for `MID(A13;1;2) = MID(A13;2;2)`. Your IF condition would be something like: `AND(MID(A13;1;2)=MID(H:H;1;2), MID(A13;2;2)=MID(H:H;2;2), MID(A13;1;2) = MID(A13;2;2))`

Comment: So column A consists of 1 value or multiple?

Comment: Column A consist with numbers with 3 and 4 digits, being 2 digits equal on each one (Ex 001, 002,.....022, 033, 044.... 202, 303, 404.... 9144, 9255.... for instamce, for number 001, it should retrive from column H the numbers 001, 002, 003......, for number 002 it should retrieve 002, 003, 004.... for number 022 should retrieve 022, 122, 222, 322, 422.... for numbers 9144 should retrieve all numbers that ends with 44... and so on

Answer (score 0):

Using Office 365 this may be a solution:

```
=LET(m,MID(A13,SEQUENCE(LEN(A13)),1),
ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL($H$2:$H$99/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|"&CONCAT(IF((LEN(A13)-1)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A13,m,"")),"?",m))&"|","|"&$H$2:$H$99&"|"))),2)))
```

Where the number is split into single digits (characters representing the digits to be more accurate). And each individual character is checked to occur less then twice. If so, the character is replaced with a `?` wildcard symbol, else the character remains.

SEARCH allows wildcard input and uses the concatenated characters (including a leading and trailing character) to filter out the values that have the duplicate numbers in the same position.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers!!, infortunately the formulas didn't work : for instance if the number in column A is 929;, they extracts the numbers 929, 931 and 1014 from column H ; it should have been 919, 929, 939, 949, 959...... :(

Comment: Updated (I used full column range for the column reference inside search. Changed it to H2:H99 (to be changed to your needs)

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't retrieve the correct numbers,for instance it returns 7,8,9 for number 008, and it should be 001,002,003,004,005,006,007,008,009 :(

Comment: 008 is not a number (in Excel) but text or a formatting, but the number representation is always 8. But I can't reproduce what you mean.

Comment: This would cover the text numbers: `=LET(m,MID(A13,SEQUENCE(LEN(A13)),1),ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|"&CONCAT(IF((LEN(A13)-1)=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A13,m,"")),"?",m))&"|","|"&$H$2:$H$99&"|")),$H$2:$H$99),2)))`